# How to export const to other components react?

Tags: reactjs

I created a file `Category.js`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export const CategoryData = (props) => {
    const [Category, setCategory] = useState('')
    fetch('https://www.amrutras.com/Category.php')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            {
                setCategory(responseJson)

                // responseJson.map((item) => Alert.alert(item.Name))
            }

            // Showing response message coming from server after inserting records.
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
        })
    return Category
}

export default CategoryData
```

I want to use this `Category` const in my other component.

I tried to do that with

```
import CategoryData from '../consts/CategoryData'
```

and using this function in `useEffect` of another component. like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(CategoryData)
    })
```

But it's not working.

Comment: CategoryData is a functional component. What are you trying to achieve my consoling it indside useEffect?

Comment: I just want to see the output of `Category` const

Comment: I am trying to get data from the server and put that data in the category const and access it to another component.

Comment: You can't use it like this. You should bring that `fetch` call inside the `useEffect` and use a local state variable to store the result. Or make it a custom hook, which would be completely redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use hooks directly within functions, unless they are custom hooks which you then cannot invoke inside other hooks but have to follow the rules of hooks to use them

You can restructure your code to implement `CategoryData` like a custom hook

```
export const useCategoryData = (props) => {
    const [Category, setCategory] = useState('')
    useEffect(() => {
       fetch('https://www.amrutras.com/Category.php')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            {
                setCategory(responseJson)

                // responseJson.map((item) => Alert.alert(item.Name))
            }

            // Showing response message coming from server after inserting records.
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
        })
    }, [])
    
    return Category
}

export default useCategoryData;
```

Now you can use it in your component like

```
function App () {
   const categoryData = useCategoryData();
   ...
}
```

SOLUTION2:

Another way to implement this is to not use custom hook but implement a normal function like

```
export const CategoryData = (props) => {
    return fetch('https://www.amrutras.com/Category.php')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
        })
}

export default CategoryData
```

and use it like

```
function App () {
   const [categoryData, setCategoryData] = useState(null);
   useEffect(() => {
       CategoryData.then(res => setCategoryData(res));
  }, []); Make sure to provide a dependency list to your useEffect otherwise you will end up in a infinite loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it as a custom hook

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export const useCategoryData = (props) => {
    const [Category, setCategory] = useState('')
    useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('https://www.amrutras.com/Category.php')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            {
                setCategory(responseJson)

                // responseJson.map((item) => Alert.alert(item.Name))
            }

            // Showing response message coming from server after inserting records.
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
        })
},[])
    return {Category}
}
```

import it like

```
import {useCategoryData} from '.......'

const {Category} = useCategoryData()
```